Selenium select fail but working successful on normal browser
My env is Windows 10, Edge 119.
This tool is used in our company internally.
Manual opertion works on this element named MainContent_ModelNamePicker_okb but when I use edgeDriver MainContent_ModelNamePicker_okb click will not work and there is not any response.
# Try both method
driver.find_element(By.ID, "MainContent_ModelNamePicker_okb").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "MainContent_ModelNamePicker_okb").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

I try to use js to operate this web
document.getElementById("xxxx").click() but it reture undefined.
document.getElementById("xxxx").click only show clicked() {native code}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
